How to implement an array that can grow up to a limit and never allocates?
I need to implement a container which has most of the functionality of vector (especially, push_back, insert, erase and sort) but never allocates memory.
I want it to start with an internal buffer of compile-time size, and I promise that it will never need to grow beyond that size.
Can I use allocator for that? If yes, how? If not, how to reuse maximum existing code from the Standard Library?
I could use an array and a separate size variable, but I like object-oriented programming, and this data structure appears often enough to warrant a dedicated class/template.

This answer in Constant-sized vector says: "There is no way to define a constant size vector.". Also why not just use std::array

Also push_back won't make sense on a fixed size array./vector The users can potentially get confused due to it as you'll be changing its usual meaning.

Also this seems to be just asking for code snippet like homework assignments do without actually explaining the things/requirements in detail and the attempt so far.

Writing from scratch what you specifically want as per your requiremenets/needs looks the best approach/idea here.

An allocator is not really a good solution to a requirement for no allocation.     There is nothing wrong with wrapping a separate size variable and a std::array within a single class (with the size of the array a compile-time constant, and member functions enforcing a requirement that the separate size variable does not exceed the array's size).    Bear in mind that, practically, the size of an array is limited by "stack size", which is often limited by quotas to be significantly less than available RAM.

You can probably use std::vector with custom allocator from a fixed size buffer, thus keeping the interface. Here is what I used a few years ago, it based on array: https://github.com/gbresearch/yadro/blob/master/container/static_vector.h

@Gene You can't do this with std::allocator, or at least not directly. Allocator requirements force it to be copyable, and the copy must be able to free the memory allocated by the original.

This is being proposed as std::inplace_vector (Previously: static_vector). Complete implementation available from many third parties, notably boost::static_vector eastl::fixedVector, folly::small_vector<T, Size, folly::small_vector_policy::NoHeap>

I think you mean "never reallocates", you would have to allocate memory at least once.

As noted in comments, there are multiple implementations.

boost::static_vector
eastl::fixedVector
folly::small_vector<T, Size, folly::small_vector_policy::NoHeap>

It's also proposed for a future C++ version.
